# how to return json response on ajax call in symfony3?

Tags: symfony

I am using symfony3:

I am calling a method via ajax call:

Controller

```
/**
     * @Route("personnel/domainlist/{id}", name="ajax_method")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function domainlist(Request $request,$id){
       $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:ENTITYNAME');          
       $res=$repository->findBy(array('COLNAME' => $id));          
      // create a JSON-response with a 200 status code

      $response = new Response(json_encode($res));    
      $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      return $response;
      die;
    }
```

form above code i am getting following result:
 print_r($res);

```
Array
(
    [0] =&gt; AppBundle\Entity\ENTITYNAME Object
        (
            [domain_id:AppBundle\Entity\ENTITYNAME:private] =&gt; 15
            [domain_title:protected] =&gt; ABC
            [domain_group_id:protected] =&gt; 1
        )
)
```

AJax code:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "domainlist/" + pdoamin_id,      
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',        
         success: function(result) {
            alert(result);
             }
          });

  });
```

Anyone can help me how can i return json to ajax method in symfony3

Answer (score 1):

You have to serialize your answer before push it to Response.
There are two ways to do it (at least I know just two ways)

1. [The Serializer Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html)
2. [Implement interface \JsonSerializable](http://php.net/manual/en/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php) (PHP version >=5.4 )

In both variants your json_encode function will be work as you expect.

I prefer second way for For its simplicity

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if Symfony 3 has the class, but in Symfony 4, you can use the JsonResponse class.

import the class into your controller

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
```

Then use one of its constructors in your return statement:

```
return new JsonResponse($dataToReturn);
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:ENTITYNAME');          
       $res=$repository->findBy(array('COL_NAME' => $id));          
       $normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer();      
       $encoder = new JsonEncoder();
       $serializer = new Serializer(array($normalizer), array($encoder));
       $response=$serializer->serialize($res, 'json');
```